# Manga where mc is a poor boy living with his mom and is dumped then gains a system

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't remember the title, but the main character is poor and lives in a village with his mom. He is dumped and gains a system and the first thing he buys is a potion buried under a tree. He drinks it then passes out and is stronger. Then he learns an acupuncture technique. Then, he finds a ton of oysters and makes a pearl farm but his fellow villagers turn greedy and try to sell them without permission. So he buy fireworks so that whoever sees them, he can alter their dreams. He alters the dreams to make them put the pearls back. He attends a party and when a bullet comes toward someone so he stops it with a needle.

Comment: Hello, do you know where the manga comes from? It could help us in finding it. Chinese (in color reading left to right), Japanese (in black and white), or Korean?

Comment: What is this system that he gains?

Comment: A system were he earns points to buy items like the fire works and potions and the acupuncture technique however it doesn't have a stat window

Comment: i think its korean

Comment: And thank you for helping me find it

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by the boy being dumped? Do you mean that he was abandoned by his mother?

Comment: No he was dumped by his girlfriend for someone richer he lives with his mom

Comment: this is 100% manhua and unfortunately there is a lot of manhua like this 

Motip: system -> OP